# placing the separately signed hash to Multiple places in PDF using itextsharp

Tags: pdf, c#-4.0, itext, signing

I want to place same externally signed hash (signature value) at multiple places in a PDF.

I have referred the page 'how-to-place-the-same-digital-signatures-to-multiple-places-in-pdf-using-itextsh' and tried to implement the work around provided by mkl (please refer this [How to place the Same Digital signatures to Multiple places in PDF using itextsharp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47526151/how-to-place-the-same-digital-signatures-to-multiple-places-in-pdf-using-itextsh)).

And it works. I ported it to get the signer bytes signed externally using web service/ api and it also works. Now due to one of the requirement I changed the way hash is being calculated.

now instead of (old one):

```
byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, "SHA256");
byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

I am trying to use (new one):

```
        int contentEstimated=8192;
        HashAlgorithm sha = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        int read = 0;
        byte[] buff = new byte[contentEstimated];
        while ((read = data.Read(buff, 0, contentEstimated)) > 0)
        {
            sha.TransformBlock(buff, 0, read, buff, 0);
        }
        sha.TransformFinalBlock(buff, 0, 0);
        byte[] hash = Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders.Hex.Encode(sha.Hash);

        string hashtext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash, 0, hash.Length); //for writing it to file or sharing it to another api
        byte[] hash1 = StringToByteArray(hashtext);

        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash1, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS); or 
        byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS); //tried both
```

and if I try to use it in existing implementation, the signature gets invalid with an error "Document has been altered or corrupt since it was signed". Can you please tell me where I am doing it wrong?

At most of the referred pages, they have used this hash generation method with an embed function where the calculated hash is getting embedded in the pdf,

```
    byte[] paddedSig = new byte[csize];
    System.Array.Copy(pk, 0, paddedSig, 0, pk.Length);
    PdfDictionary dic2 = new PdfDictionary();
    dic2.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));
    appearance.Close(dic2);
```

Thank you.
- Tanmay

Comment: It should work using just `sha.Hash`.

Comment: yes.. it worked with sha.hash. But if tried to get a hash string by sha.hash then it doesn't work. I tried.. 

string hashtext1 = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);
string hashtext = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hash, 0, hash.Length);

With this I want to have a 64 bytes hash string. Is it possible?

Comment: The basic premise to change the implementation is to get 64 byte long hash.. I am looking for the ways to generate a document hash in a way, ----- 1 - to convert it to a 64 byte long string and 2 - use the hash byte array to get a valid signature in above implementation

Comment: You can't put anything you want in the hash, remember that the hash is recreated to be compared when the verification is done. If you need a 64 byte long hash try a SHA512.

Comment: As @Paulo said, the hash value parameter you put into `getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes` needs to be the result of applying the digest algorithm to the document data. You have the choice of digest algorithm, though, and SHA512 would result in a 64 byte value. Don't forget, though, to accordingly adapt the digest algorithm name you use in the `PdfPKCS7` constructor. On the other hand, if sha512 is not what you want, you probably should explain the background of your 64 bytes requirement...

Comment: I don't want to use sha512.. basically the document hash/ signer bytes are getting signed by 3rd party service, which requires  **SHA256 hash value of the document in Hex format**

Comment: Is there any way to use `dic.Put(PdfName.CONTENTS, new PdfString(paddedSig).SetHexWriting(true));` in this implementation ?because it seems, to use hash in hex format, I have set the dictionary property.. Can anyone suggest any changes?

Comment: @mkl Any suggestions? Because with another method I can sign a single page with the signature returned by service (PKCS#7 / CMS signature), but then when I try to add that same signature at multiple places, I cannot do it.

Comment: All we can say seeing your attempt is that your code change makes no sense at all. You now say *"3rd party service, which requires SHA256 hash value of the document in Hex format"*. If it requires the *document* hash, I assume it returns a full-fledged CMS signature container. Does it? If otherwise it does not, it makes no sense for it to require the document hash; instead it should require the hash of the bytes to immediately, directly sign. Thus, please add backgrounds concerning that sign service to your question.

Comment: @mkl you are right. The service returns full-fledged CMS signature container (PKCS#7 / CMS signature). which I was to able to integrate for single page signing but not for multi-page. Actually I got to know the response format recently, that's why I was not able to mention it in the original question itself. My bad.

Comment: *"that's why I was not able to mention it in the original question itself"* - you can always edit your question to include additional information, there is an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48943703/edit) link right underneath. But please refrain from replacing your question with a completely different one, at least if there already are answers to the original question, only add additional required information that way.

Comment: will keep that in mind.. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments the OP clarified that he wants to adapt the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762053/1729265) to using an external signing service which accepts a document hash (more exactly a *SHA256 hash value of the document in Hex format*) and returns a full-fledged CMS signature container.

In this case the original `AllPagesSignatureContainer` method `Sign`

```cs
public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
{
    String hashAlgorithm = externalSignature.GetHashAlgorithm();
    PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, hashAlgorithm, false);
    IDigest messageDigest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest(hashAlgorithm);
    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, hashAlgorithm);
    byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
    byte[] extSignature = externalSignature.Sign(sh);
    sgn.SetExternalDigest(extSignature, null, externalSignature.GetEncryptionAlgorithm());
    return sgn.GetEncodedPKCS7(hash, null, null, null, CryptoStandard.CMS);
}
```

has to be changed to not itself create a CMS container using the `PdfPKCS7 sgn` but merely calculate the document hash, send it to the service and use the container returned by the service:

```cs
public byte[] Sign(Stream data)
{
    String hashAlgorithm = externalSignature.GetHashAlgorithm();
    IDigest messageDigest = DigestUtilities.GetDigest(hashAlgorithm);
    byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.Digest(data, hashAlgorithm);
    byte[] hexHash = Org.BouncyCastle.Utilities.Encoders.Hex.Encode(hash);
    string hexHashString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hexHash , 0, hexHash.Length);
    var response = [... call service with document hash hexHashString ...];
    byte[] signatureContainer = [... extract binary CMS container from response ...];
    return signatureContainer;
}
```

The OP has not mentioned anything about the response format, so I cannot say more about the *extract binary CMS container from `response`* part. It may include selecting one attribute of a larger response structure, it may include decoding an encoded value (probably a Hex encoded string), ...

Comment: Needed to decode it and it worked. I was missing the point before returning the container, I was not removing the 'SetExternalDigest' statement. That's why I was getting corrupted signature. Thanks a ton. - Tanmay